# Wordpress blocking iframe automatically created

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have installed this theme: http://www.designwall.com/product/dw-minion/ in my self-hosted Wordpress

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9outg.png

[image]

But the thing is whenever I go to a post, I can't highlight nor click on anything because an iframe is blocking the whole page! I do not know this generated iframe and it only happens on the said theme. Anyone got an idea what it is and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. Here's the answer: http://www.neilmarion.com/index.php/fixing-an-obtrusive-wordpress-theme/